# Adjusting scrollview gives error with offset

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

I am using scrollview for my topCardView and bottomView. When I try to scroll everytime it gives me an error of invalid frame dimensions or sometimes it get freeze. Bound preference SizePreferenceKey tried to update multiple times per frame.

How can I fix this? Any help I really appreciate.

My completed code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
            GeometryReader { reader in
                topCardView
                    .offset(y: -reader.frame(in: .global).minY)
                    .frame(width: reader.size.width, height: reader.frame(in: .global).minY + 450)
            }
            .frame(height: 450)
            
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                BottomView
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 32)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .background(
                Color(red: 232/255, green: 230/255, blue: 225/255)
                    .cornerRadius(40)
            )
            .offset(y: -25)
        })
    }
 
    @ViewBuilder
    private var topCardView: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHGrid(rows: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 1), spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0..<2) { _ in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                        .fill(Color(red: 248/255, green: 250/255, blue: 220/255))
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 377)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private var BottomView: some View {
        ForEach(0..<2) { _ in
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Fastest Near You")
                    .bold()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32 * 6, height: 35)
                
                Text("Order your food here")
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32 * 4, height: 25)
                
                LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 2), spacing: 12) {
                    ForEach(0..<4) { _ in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                            .fill(Color(red: 248/255, green: 250/255, blue: 220/255))
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2 - 24, height: 200)
                        
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 20)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Image:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: I tried your code and the error message only appears after scrolling up quite significantly. This is presumably because `minY + 450` is negative. You can fix by changing it to `height: max(1, reader.frame(in: .global).minY + 450)`. But I am wondering, why you need to be setting a dynamic frame height anyway?

Comment: @BenzyNeez It's still freezing scrollview sometimes. Dynamic height I used so when I scroll up the `topCardView` goes up just kind of parallax effect.

Comment: @BenzyNeez is there any other way I slightly move `topCardView` to upward direction while scrolling up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asking in the comments, why you were setting a dynamic frame height at all. You replied to say, you want to create a parallax effect.

I think this can be achieved without using a dynamic frame height:

- the top section can simply use the full height of the container that surrounds it (the `GeometryReader`)
- for the parallax effect, a y-offset can be applied to the top section that is a fraction of the scrolled height
- if you are running iOS 17 or above, you can use `.frame(in: .scrollView)` to reference the coordinate space of the `ScrollView`
- for earlier iOS versions, you could name the coordinate space of the `ScrollView` instead
- to manage the initial spacing between the two sections, use a `VStack` that contains them both
- I would suggest applying a `zIndex` to the bottom view, just to be quite sure that it is always shown above the top view
- an outer `GeometryReader` can be used to measure the size of the screen, instead of using `UIScreen.main` (which is deprecated).

So maybe try something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { outer in
            let screenSize = outer.size
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 40) {
                    GeometryReader { reader in
                        let minY = reader.frame(in: .scrollView).minY
                        topCardView
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .offset(y: -minY / 2)
                    }
                    .frame(height: screenSize.height / 2)

                    VStack(spacing: 40) {
                        bottomView(screenSize: screenSize)
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                            .fill(Color(red: 232/255, green: 230/255, blue: 225/255))
                    )
                    .zIndex(1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private var topCardView: some View {
        // content as before
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func bottomView(screenSize: CGSize) -> some View {
        // content as before, but using screenSize instead of UIScreen.main.bounds
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thank you so much. Its perfect. Last one thing if I have to add spacing from top because I have a navigationbar which hides some part of topView. What would you recommend to me where I place padding?

Comment: @IOSTech Pleased to hear it helped, thanks for accepting the answer. To make space for the navigation bar, you could try applying the top padding to the `ScrollView`. This will break the contact with the safe area inset at the top, so it will no longer scroll off the top of the screen. But presumably, your navigation bar is covering that area anyway? Alternatively, you could apply the padding to `topCardView` itself.